# Cuando abro otra App diferente a la mía y recibo una notificacion los métodos de AppDelegate no son llamados swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, background, notification

La situación es la siguiente, cuando le doy tap a una notificación pero tengo en ese momento una app abierta diferente a la mía ninguno de estos dos métodos son llamados sin explicación. Un método en teoría es cuando es en background y otro en foreground. Esto solo pasa cuando ejecuto la app, abro una aplicación diferente a la mía y antes de enviar la primera notificación APNs, envió la notificación y digamos que a ningún método de los propuestos entra. Si lo hago de la forma contraria de antes de abrir cualquier app y en background si mando una notificación y después abro otra app entra al método de UIBackgroundFetchResult, entonces no sé que me faltara o porque pasa esto.

```
    @UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{

 
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        notificationAuthorization(application)
        Service.initService(externalAppId: "1:962904260310")
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging()
            .setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.unknown)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("entramosssss")
        let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
        if state == .background{
            print("pero que poasooooo")
            Service.registerDataNotification(didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo)
        }
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    
    func registerCellphone(cellphone: String?){
        Service.registerCellphone(cellphone: cellphone)
    }
    
    fileprivate func notificationAuthorization(_ application: UIApplication) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
      withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
      print("userNotificationCenter")
      Service.registerDataNotification(didReceiveRemoteNotification: notification.request.content.userInfo)
      if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        completionHandler([[.banner, .list, .sound, .badge]])
      } else {
        completionHandler([[.alert, .sound, .badge]])
        }
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        Service.registerEventOpened(didReceive: response)
        completionHandler()
    }
}

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
    Service.saveToken(didReceiveRegistrationToken: fcmToken)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice una prueba en el simulador con una notificación APNS y la función que se ejecuta con un punto de interrupción es esta:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                         didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                         withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
    completionHandler()
}
```

Al parecer no tienes esta función en tu código, te recomendaría agregar todas las funciones para las notificaciones tanto para el `AppDelegate` como para el `NotificationCenter`

Comment: como va todo, ese método siempre lo e tenido, el cual lo utilizo es cuando le doy tap a una notificación, ese es ejecuto pero digamos cuando es la primera vez que ejecuto la app, abro otra app y envío una notificacion APNs, a ninguno de esos tres métodos llega info. De todas maneras ya coloco todo el app delegate que tengo. Es muy raro, hoy haciendo pruebas me di cuenta de ello.

Comment: Esa prueba es la que hice, abrí otra app y al presionar en la notificación se abre mi app. Si colocas un punto de interrupción no entra en ningún método?

Comment: si entra al metodo de UIBackgroundFetchResult pero solo hasta que le doy tap y la idea es que siempre entre a ese método desde que me llega la notificacion, pero en este caso especifico la primera vez desde otra app no entra ni a ese ni a ningún otro.